# Select and iterate through elements and sub elements with same name (Jsoup)

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to parse through a page by jsoup. The page has elements with tags `div`,`h3`,`a` etc. I want to parse through the elements and select `a` (i.e. title) to be displayed in `jList`.

As an example, the page looks like:

```
<div class="start">
    <div class="g">
        <div class="abc">
            <a class="picture" href="www.img.com"><img src="img" alt="image1"></a>
            <div class="xyz">
                <h3 class="_r">
                    <a class="title" href="www.example.com" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','adf','','ahahh','','',event)">THIS IS <em>example</em>1</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g">
        <div class="abc">
            <a class="picture" href="www.img.com"><img src="img" alt="image2"></a>
            <div class="xyz">
                <h3 class="_r">
                    <a class="title" href="www.example.com" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','adf','','ahahh','','',event)">lead by this<em>example</em></a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g">
        <div class="abc">
            <a class="picture" href="www.img.com"><img src="img" alt="image3"></a>
            <div class="xyz">
                <h3 class="_r">
                    <a class="title" href="www.example.com" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','adf','','ahahh','','',event)">showed<em>example</em>for the people</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g">
        <div class="abc">
            <a class="picture" href="www.img.com"><img src="img" alt="image4"></a>
            <div class="xyz">
                <h3 class="_r">
                    <a class="title" href="www.example.com" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','adf','','ahahh','','',event)">we set<em>example</em>for people</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=example&tbm=nws&source=lnms";
String title = "";
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Chrome").timeout(5000).get();
    Elements e = doc.select("div.g");
    for (Element e1 : e) {
        title = e1.getElementsByTag("a").text();
    }
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.addElement(title);
    jList.setModel(listModel);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The output that I got was the title of the last element `div.g`:

`we set example for people`

I want to select the title from each `div.g` and display each title separately in `jList` as item like this:

```
THIS IS example 1
lead by this example
showed example for the people
we set example for people
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you assign the scraped data to `title` in a loop and then **outside** the loop you assign `title` to the jlist. So, the value of `title` once the loop has completed will always be the last value.

Replace this ...

```
for (Element e1 : e) {
    title = e1.getElementsByTag("a").text();
}
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
listModel.addElement(title);
```

With this ...

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (Element e1 : e) {
    listModel.addElement(e1.getElementsByTag("a").text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't add title each time. The loop replace each time title with the new value found and after the loop you add it in the list. Something like this might work the way you want it :

```
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();  
    for (Element e1 : e) {
       listModel.addElement(e1.getElementsByTag("a").text());
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly! :). Just another question, how can i get the link of the title?

Comment: According to [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls), `e1.getElementsByTag("a").attr("href")` should do the trick.

Comment: @user7146946 `e1.getElementsByTag("a").attr("href")`